# Adding strings to an array of strings is somehow changing the previous strings in the array

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I've written this function intended to add strings to an array of strings, each time creating enough memory for the new string before putting it in, and `realloc`ing the size of the array when it gets full. Here's an example of my code:

```
#define INITIAL 10

int addtoarray(char **A, int *size, int n, char *b);

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char **D, a[3]="ab"; /*'a' is arbitrary for this example */
    int n=0, size=INITIAL, i, j;

    D = (char**)malloc(INITIAL*sizeof(char));

    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        n = addtoarray(D, &size, n, a);

        /* print the contents of D */
        printf("Dict: ");
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
            printf("D[%d]='%s' ", j, D[j]);    
        } printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int
addtoarray(char **A, int *size, int n, char *b) {

    if (*size == n) {
        /* Array is full, give more space */ 
        realloc(A, *size = 2*(*size));
        assert(A);
    }

    printf("Adding '%s' to D[%d], size of D = %d\n", b, n, *size);

    /* Create space in array for new string */
    A[n] = (char*)malloc(strlen(b)+1);
    assert(A[n]);

    /* Put the new string in array! */
    strcpy(A[n], b);
    n++;

    return n;
}
```

In this example 'n' is the number of strings in the array. The output of this code is:

```
Adding 'ab' to D[0], size of D = 10
D: D[0]='ab' 
Adding 'ab' to D[1], size of D = 10
D: D[0]='ab' D[1]='ab' 
Adding 'ab' to D[2], size of D = 10
D: D[0]='?K@S?' D[1]='ab' D[2]='ab'
```

As you can see the third time the function is called, the string goes into the array fine. But the first string in the array is somehow changed. I have no idea why this has happened, but I am pretty sure it is happening on the `A[n] = (char*)malloc(strlen(b)+1);` line in the function.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong? (Also if you have any tips for other parts of my code)

Comment: This: `realloc(A, *size = 2*(*size));` needs to be `A = realloc(A, *size = 2*(*size));` at a bare minimum; allocations can move after a `realloc()`.  The assert afterwards is a tacky (and dangerous) error handling mechanism, doubly so if you disable assertions in 'production' code.  You may use the `assert()` only if you back it up with an actual `if` that will be used at run-time to validate the reallocation.

Comment: You need to check the return value of realloc. When you get to it, that's where the address of your new memory will be returned. That's not this problem, but thought I'd mention it. Your code runs fine here after adding the proper includes.

Comment: At this stage I've just been told to use an assert to make sure the malloc or realloc didn't return a null pointer. Would you recommend something more like if (!ptr) {printf("Malloc failed\n");exit(EXIT_FAILURE);} where ptr is the pointer returned by malloc of realloc?

Comment: An explicit test like that, yes.  If you are going to exit on an error, then I'd rather call a function which prints the error on standard error (not standard output) and exits.  If you'll return, then you can't use the `ptr = realloc(per, new size);` idiom.  You must use: `void *newptr = realloc(oldster, new size);` as otherwise you' round leaked the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array of string, you need room for size of `char *`:

```
malloc(INITIAL*sizeof(char));
```

should be

```
malloc(INITIAL*sizeof(char *));
```

And in the `realloc` part:

```
realloc(A, *size = 2*(*size));
```

as pointed out by Jonathan Leffler, `realloc` returns a pointer to the reallocated memory block, you need a triple pointer to pass (and manipulate its value with the dereference operator) a pointer to string:

```
int addtoarray(char ***A, int *size, int n, char *b) {
   ...
   *A = realloc(*A, (*size = 2*(*size)) * sizeof(char *));
   assert(*A);
   ...
```

and in your `main` function:

```
n = addtoarray(&D, &size, n, a);
```

Comment: Well, partly...the code must also capture the result of `realloc()`; the original pointer is no longer valid and only the new pointer returned is still valid.

Comment: Could you please explain the reasoning behind using a triple pointer? I'm not sure that I understand completely.

Comment: @SirBarkalot, you need a triple pointer to alter the address of a double pointer inside a function, or you can return the new reallocated pointer and pass a pointer to `n`

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you're not assigning the pointer returning from realloc.

```
realloc(A, *size = 2*(*size));
```

should be :

```
A = realloc(A, *size = 2*(*size));
```

whithout this, `A` is still pointing to the the old memory space.